# A problem on nested radicals

Tags: sequences-and-series, proof-verification, nested-radicals

Find the value of $x$ for all $a>b^2$ if:

$$\large x=\sqrt{a-b\sqrt{a+b\sqrt{a-b{\sqrt{a+b.......}}}}}$$

My attempt

$$\large x=\sqrt{a-b\sqrt{(a+b)x}}$$

$$\large x^4=(a-b)^2(a+b)x$$

$$\large x=((a-b)^2(a+b))^{1/3}$$ (real root)

Question: Is my solution correct??

Comment: Division by zero!!! $x=0$ is also a valid solution.

Comment: @AlexR $$a \neq b$$

Comment: Can you explain the simplification you did when taking the fourth power? It does not look right. Oh, wait a minute: Same thing with the initial equation for $x$. Or did you mean to ask about $x=\sqrt{(a-b)\sqrt{(a+b)\sqrt{(a-b){\sqrt{(a+b)\sqrt{…}}}}}}$ ?

Comment: @HaraldHanche-Olsen I cancelled $x$ by $x$ since $x \neq 0$, then I took the cube root.

Comment: No, before that. (I edited my comment while you were answering it.)

Comment: The fourth power of $x=\sqrt{a-b\sqrt{a+bx}}$ (which I think you should have) would be $x^4=a^2-2ab\sqrt{a+bx}+b^2(a+bx)$.

Comment: @HaraldHanche-Olsen I get it, thanks

Comment: @HaraldHanche-Olsen This has turned really nasty, I don't think my approach is going to work anymore

Comment: @harry $a\neq b$ is irrelevant to this. Still $x=0$ solves your equation.

Comment: I have to roolback but I don't see the option

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Your approach is not right unless your original equation was: $$x=\sqrt{(a-b)\sqrt{(a+b)\sqrt{(a-b)\sqrt{(a+b)\cdots}}}}$$

However, it's almost there.

$\displaystyle\begin{align}
x & = \sqrt{a-b\sqrt{a+b\sqrt{a-b\sqrt{a+b\cdots}}}}
\\ x & =\sqrt{a-b\sqrt{a+bx}}
\\x^2 & = a-b\sqrt{a+bx}
\\(a-x^2)^2 & = b^2(a+bx) 
\\ a^2-2ax^2+x^4 & = ab^2 + b^3x
\\ 0 & = x^4-2ax^2-b^3 x +a^2-ab^2
\\ 0 & = (x^2 +bx-a+b^2)(x^2-bx-a)
\\ \therefore x & \in \left\{\frac {-b-\sqrt{4a-3b^2}}2, \frac{-b+\sqrt{4a-3b^2}}2, \frac{b-\sqrt{4a+b^2}}2, \frac{b+\sqrt{4a+b^2}}2 \right\}
\end{align}$

Now apply the criteria $a>b^2$ to select among them for the satisfactory answer.

Comment: $x$ will converge to one of these. I don't understand four answers.

Comment: @harry among the 4 answers, two of them is negative and one $> \sqrt{a}$. So one can rule them out.

Comment: The quaternary equation has four roots.  Choose among them.

Comment: @GrahamKemp I couldn't rule out except first and third :(

Comment: @achillehui Why should I rule the one $>\sqrt{a}$?

Comment: @harry, by definition $x = \sqrt{a - (\text{something non-negative})}$.

Comment: @achillehui Thanks a million.....

Comment: @achillehui so 2nd one is the answer.

Comment: @GrahamKemp What was your motivation for the factorization? it looks awesome!!

Comment: @achillehui What was the motivation for the factorization?

Comment: @harry, you have a quartic equation. The first thing one should try is determine whether it can factorize into simpler pieces. If possible, we throw it to a CAS and ask a computer to do the boring part for us ;-p

Comment: @achillehui I am interested in the boring part ;-p

Answer (score 1):

Here's another one:

$$\text{Let} x=\sqrt{a-b\sqrt{a+b\sqrt{a-b\sqrt{a+b\cdots}}}}$$

$$\text{Let}y=\sqrt{a+b\sqrt{a-b\sqrt{a+b\sqrt{a-b\cdots}}}}$$

Now $$x^2=a-by---1$$ and $$y^2=a+bx----2$$ $$\implies x^2-y^2=-b(x+y)$$ $$\implies(x+y)(x-y+b)=0$$(Considering only positive solutions of $x$) $$y=x+b$$, putting it in eq $2$, $$x^2+bx+b^2-a=0$$, on Solving:

$$\large x=\frac{-b+\sqrt{4a-3b^2}}{2}$$